# Oracle Linux 7 repository rpm files not available

Tags: package, repository, oraclelinux

I just created an Oracle Autonomous Linux 7 instance on Oracle Cloud, and I was wondering how can I set other repositories up. According to the manual I should use the following to list all available repo rpms:

```
yum list *release-el7*
```

This will list the following:

```
ksplice-release-el7.x86_64
oraclelinux-release-el7.x86_64
```

The manual then suggests to run something like this:

```
yum install oracle-softwarecollection-release-el7
```

But it is clear that it won't install, as it wasn't listed previously. So I looked what does yum.oracle.com say. According to them, I should check if I have the default oracle repo package with this:

```
rpm -q oraclelinux-release-el7
```

The result is the following:

```
package oraclelinux-release-el7 is not installed
```

Which is strange, as it was listed just a few lines above. Nevertheless, if I try to install this package with this:

```
yum install oraclelinux-release-el7
```

I get the following:

```
Package oraclelinux-release-el7-1.0-8.el7.x86_64 is obsoleted by al-config-1.0-8.el7.noarch which is already installed
```

Which means I'm back to square one, I'm going in circles now. This is the current default Autonomous image you can select from Oracle's cloud console, so I haven't changed anything.

Does anybody have any suggestions what should I try now? The documentation is clearly not helpful anymore.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you still need ol7_latest repo to install your package?
It was the case with early autonomous linux yum configuration, but chances are you probably already have the package you are looking for, in al7 repo that comes by default with the image.